# javascript- create maximal connected graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have following inputs, for example:

```
events = [
   { start: 30, end: 150},
   { start: 540, end: 600},
   { start: 560, end: 620},
   { start: 610, end: 670}
]
```

start, end means the minutes passed since 9 am or whatever.

I want output like this,

```
events = [
    [{ start: 30, end: 150}],
    [{ start: 540, end: 600}, {start: 560, end: 620}, {start: 610, end: 670}]
]
```

I have a function determine whether two objects collide in time.

```
var isOverLapping =  function(event1, event2){

        if (event1.end >= event2.start && event1.start <= event2.end) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
};
```

For example, I have four events as you can see in the beginning, let's say 1, 2 ,3 ,4.

since 2 collide with 3 in time, 3 collide with 2 and 4 in time, and 4 collide with 3 in time.
So they should belong to one set [2,3,4], which is `[{ start: 540, end: 600}, {start: 560, end: 620}, {start: 610, end: 670}]`

I know it might be confused. Hope this will make my thought more clear.Think collide in time as connection. If A is connect to B and B is connect to C, so A is connect to C as well, as a result, they should belong to one set.

I need help in writing this in JavaScript. Any thoughts? I didn't find an good way to do this at the moment I post this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your isOverLapping function loops through the entire set - it will always return true if the argument is an event in that set (i.e. an event always overlaps with itself). Is that what you intended?

Comment: @PartyLich , thanks for pointing that, I need to make adjustment to that. I want to think this as maximum connected graph problem, every event is a node in a graph, if it's not collide with other events, it's a graph with one single node, it two events collide, they should belong to one graph.

Comment: @XinruiMa +1 for interesting question. To clarify, consider A,B,C with start in numerical order. What if A and C collide with B but no collision between A and C?

Comment: @Dinesh If A and C collide with B but no collision between A and C, A, B, C should still belong to one set, think it this way, A is connected with B and B is connected to C, so A and C is connected.

Comment: @Dinesh Actually this is the first step of resolving a calendar issue, which is if two events collide in time, they must have same width. So I have to determine which events should have the same width, in this case, the events in same set should have the same width.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
events = [
   { start: 30, end: 150},
   { start: 540, end: 600},
   { start: 560, end: 620},
   { start: 610, end: 670}
]

var sets=[], max, arr=[];

events.sort(function(a,b){return a.start-b.start}) // sort by start time

if(events.length){
    max=events[0].end
    arr.push(events[0])
}

for(var i=1;i<events.length;i++){
    var event = events[i];
    if(event.start <= max){ // overlap (we already know that event.start >= the one before )
        arr.push(event) // push event
        max=Math.max(max, event.end) // update max
    }else{
        sets.push(arr.slice(0)); // push what we have till now
        arr=[]; // clear array
        max=event.end;  // update max
        arr.push(event) // push event
    } 
}
sets.push(arr.slice(0)); // push remaining
console.log(sets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check both (start and end) if at least one is inside the range, then object belongs to a second group. Try this function:

```
var isOverLapping =  function(event){

    // "calendar" on line below should ref the element on which fc has been called 
    for(var i = 0 ; i < events.length; i++) {
        if ((event.end >= events[i].start && event.end <= events[i].end)
            || (event.start >= events[i].start && event.start <= events[i].end)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: do we have the same logic? 

if (event1.end >= event2.start && event1.start <= event2.end) {
            return true;
        }
return false;

Comment: No, you need check if the start or the end are in the other event range. (e1.start >= e2.start && e1.start <= e2.end) || (e1.end >= e2.start && e1.start <= e2.end) there are 2 conditions with an "or"

Comment: You need to compare each event with all others, and maybe the result will be more than 2 groups as @Dinesh says